# Problema Arrays

Tags: java, array

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que tengo lo siguiente:

```
int[] partidos = new int[4];
int[] votos = new int[4];
int[][] tcocientes = new int[4][8];
int[] concejales = new int[4];

String partido[];
partido = new String[4];
partido[0] = "PP";
partido[1] = "PSOE";
partido[2] = "Podemos";
partido[3] = "Ciudadanos";

int censo = 240000;
int divisor;

Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

for (int i = 0; i < partidos.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("Introduce el número de votos para el partido " + partido[i]);
    votos[i] = teclado.nextInt();
    teclado.nextLine();
}


for (int i = 0; i < tcocientes.length; i++) {
    divisor = 0;
    System.out.println(divisor);
    for (int j = 0; j < tcocientes[i].length; j++) {
        divisor = divisor + 1;
        tcocientes[i][j] = votos[i] / divisor;
        System.out.println("" + tcocientes[i][j]);
    }
```

Ahora lo que quiero es que guarde los 8 números de votos mayores y que sume un concejal al partido correspondiente. Puede que un partido acabe teniendo varios concejales.

Me imagino que hay que utilizar 3 bucles for, utilizar una variable mayor, etc.
Pero por mucho que pruebo no consigo que funcione.

Me encuentra los mayores, pero después no soy capaz de almacenarlos donde corresponde.

Answer (score 1):

```
package stackoverflow;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class StackOverflow {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] partidos = new int[4];
    int[] votos = new int[4];
    int[][] tcocientes = new int[4][8];
    int[] concejales = new int[4];

    //INICIALIZO LOS NUMEROS DE CONCEJALES
    for (int i = 0; i < concejales.length; i++) {
        concejales[i] = 0;   
    }

    String partido[];
    partido = new String[4];
    partido[0] = "PP";
    partido[1] = "PSOE";
    partido[2] = "Podemos";
    partido[3] = "Ciudadanos";

    int censo = 240000;
    int divisor = 0;
    int voto = 0;

    Scanner teclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    for (int i = 0; i < partidos.length; i++) {
        System.out.print("Introduce el número de votos para el partido (" + partido[i] + "): ");
        votos[i] = teclado.nextInt();
        teclado.nextLine();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < tcocientes.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < tcocientes[i].length; j++) {
            divisor += 1;
            tcocientes[i][j] = votos[voto] / divisor;
        }
        divisor=0; //RENUEVO EL DIVISOR A 0
        voto++; // INCREMENTO EL INDICE DE VOTOS, QUE COINCIDE CON EL DE FILAS DE VOTOS (4)
    }

    //IMPRIMO LOS 4 PARTIDOS Y SUS VOTOS EN FORMA DE MATRIZ
    System.out.println("-Total de votos de los 4 partidos-");
    for (int i = 0; i < tcocientes.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(partido[i]+": ");
        for (int j = 0; j < tcocientes[i].length; j++) {
            System.out.print(tcocientes[i][j] + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }

    //SEGUIMIENTO DE VOTOS DE LA PRIMERA COLUMNA
    int mayor = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < tcocientes.length; j++) {
          System.out.print(tcocientes[j][0] + " "); 
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < partido.length; i++) {
        mayor = tcocientes[0][0];
        if(tcocientes[i][0] > mayor){
            mayor = tcocientes[i][0];
            mayor = i;
        }
    }

    concejales[mayor] += 1;

    System.out.println("\nConcejales de la primera ronda incrementados");
    System.out.println("Partido ganador: "+ partido[mayor] + ", concejales: " +concejales[mayor]);


   }

}
```

Lo he hecho solo con la primera ronda de votos pero las demás siguen el mismo proceso saludos

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque es solamente código.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2882/)